# Callback error in Plotly/Dash app - Python

Tags: python, function, callback, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have this code for my dash application which is supposed to display one graph out of 3 graphs based on the dropdown menu (id = 'graph-selector'). The excel file will get updated on a daily basis, therefore I am using the Interval component:

```
@app.callback(Output('graph', 'figure'),
                  [Input(component_id='graph-selector', component_property='value')],
                  [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
    def update_figures(n):

        df = pd.read_excel('/Results.xls')
    
        fig_viability = px.scatter(df, x =...)
    
        fig_diameter = px.scatter(df, x =...)
    
        fig_concentration = px.scatter(df, x =...)
    
        def select_graph(value):
            if value == 'fig_viability':
                return fig_viability
            elif value == 'fig_diameter':
                return fig_diameter
            else:
                return fig_concentration
```

It gives me this error though:

"TypeError: update_figures() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given."

Does anyone know how to solve it? I definitely messed up with the callback order/logic here..

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You callback has two inputs, but the function signature has only one argument `n`; it must have two to match the inputs. Hence, you should change the function signature to something like,

```
 def update_figures(n, m):
```